# How to create a new DistributedFunction

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

This new paradigm of programming is very new to me. I would like to replace the anonymous function in `.map()` by a defined `DistributedFunction` in a given class. But I'm not sure how to create the new function.

I have the following pipeline:

```
p.drawFrom(KafkaSources.kafka(properties, topic, "topicX", "topicY"))
 .map(e -> {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    KafkaMessage kafkaMessage = gson.fromJson(e.getValue().toString(), 
    KafkaMessage.class);

    byte[] encodedData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(kafkaMessage.getData());

    try {
       kafkaMessage.setData(new String(encodedData, "utf-8"));
    } catch (Exception e1) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    return kafkaMessage;             
  })
 .map(m -> m.getData())
 .drainTo(Sinks.logger());
```

Based on some Jet examples, I ended up with the following:

```
p.drawFrom(KafkaSources.kafka(properties, topic, "topicX", "topicY"))
 .map(KafkaHelper::decodeKafkaMessage)
 .map(m -> m.getData())
 .drainTo(Sinks.logger());
```

KafkaHelper class:

```
public final class KafkaHelper implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3556269069192202060L;

    public static KafkaMessage decodeKafkaMessage(Map.Entry<Object,Object> entry) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        KafkaMessage kafkaMessage = gson.fromJson(entry.getValue().toString(), KafkaMessage.class);

        byte[] encodedData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(kafkaMessage.getData());

        try {
            kafkaMessage.setData(new String(encodedData, "utf-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         return kafkaMessage;            
    }   

}
```

Does this approach follow the specification/requirement to pass a `DistributedFunction` to `.map()`? If yes, why? If not, what changes should I do to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in both your examples you're creating and passing an instance of `DistributedFunction` to `map()`. Java 8 has a rule by which the lambda function in your first example and the method reference in your second example are used to create a synthetic subtype of `DistributedFunction` that implements its Single Abstract Method ("SAM") with the code you supplied.

Your `KafkaHelper` doesn't have to be `Serializable` because you never instantiate it. you can also put the static method `decodeKafkaMessage` in any other class because it has no dependency to the class instance.